# Combine JavaEE with Behaviour Driven Development (BDD)

Tags: jakarta-ee, bdd, acceptance-testing, jboss-arquillian

I'm currently building an application based on JavaEE 7 and I would like to use BDD / Behaviour Driven Development to write the tests.

To setup the test environment, Arquillian seems to be the best choice.

To use jBehave or Cucumber JVM in combination with Arquillian, I found some projects, but they don't seem to be very mature and popular yet:
- Cuke in Space (https://github.com/cukespace/cukespace)
- Arquillian JBehave TestRunner
- JBehave JUnit Runner

How do you implement BDD acceptance tests in combination with JavaEE development? Which technologies do you use?

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

Arquillian is a comprehensive suite that helps to execute your tests inside container.
Further there are several plugins and extensions that some of them has been developed and mature , some are less while others are under development.

For example : Arquillian Persistence Extension , this is very helpful in my case. As my application is solely deals with the database with a less business logic, Hence APE helps me seeding and cleaning database while with less messy code and in seconds. It also helps me to compare data tables etc, well there are some amazing features shipped with almost every extension.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would recommend [Arquillian Persistence Extension](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-extension-persistence) for database population and [Fest](https://github.com/alexruiz/fest-assert-2.x) for BDD-style asertions.
Not yet I looked at the Cucumber JVM, nor jBehave.

But following article: [Integrating Arquillian and JBehave](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2099020/open-source-tools/integrating-arquillian-and-jbehave.html) is really interesting and may be what you are looking for.

Hope it helps